# How to set up https for a node.js server running on docker in aws EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, https

I have a dockerised node.js/express app running on an aws ec2 instance container. Right now my app is running on a domain name hosted by aws route 53. When I go to the domain name the protocol used is http. How can I set up https for a node.js server running on docker in aws EC2?

This is what I have done so far.

1. I have set up a load-balancer on my ec2 instance with the target being https port 433.
2. I have a certificate with aws certificate manager with domain name as *.example.com. Issued by aws.
3. Do I need to do anything with docker since my app is being accessed through it. Does it need any https-enabling configuration?

Now this is where I get stuck. From [this documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/) I can see that I need a copy of the certificate in my server for https to work with my server.

1. Where do I get this copy? So I can put it in my server. Do I even need to do that?
2. Is the certificate in my aws certificate manager same as any other certificate issued by a certificate authority? If yes How can I see the private and public keys used in the https encryption?

I am new to devops and aws. If you could outline your answer in steps, from the beginning, it would be much appreciated. I have a dockerised node.js/express app running on an aws ec2 instance container accessible by an aws route53 hosted domain name. From here how can I change the default connection protocol from http to https?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Load Balancer is nice enough to append an extra request header to the request (x-forwarded-proto) which tells us from which protocol the request originated from. We can use this in an Express middleware to do redirections:

```
function forceHttps(req, res, next) {
    const xfp =
      req.headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"] || req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"];
    if (xfp === "http") {
      res.redirect(301, `https://${hostname}${req.url}`);
    } else {
      next();
    }
 }

server.use(forceHttps);
```

or use the npm package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@crystallize/elasticloadbalancer-express-force-https

```
const express = require('express');
const forceHttps = require('@crystallize/elasticloadbalancer-express-force-https');

const server = express();
server.use(forceHttps());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but tried it and nothing happened. When I `console.log(xfp)`, it comes back `undefined` and when I try to type the domain name on the browser (https://example.com) with https, it says site can not be reached. Could you please give me step by step guide from having a fresh running ec2 instance without any configurations on how to configure https on a dockerised nodejs/express app. Thank you.